# why is this variable returning "undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't figure out why the global variable `isMob` is returning undefined after trying to set it through an `if` statement.

I have been futting around with this for a bit now and can seem to find the answer.

```
var isMob;
var mobMenClicked = false;
var scrnRefresh = false;

$('.mobileMen').click(launchMenu);  


function scaleSite()
{               
    scaleVideo();
    scaleMenu();        
}   



function scaleMenu()
{
    isMob=0;
    if($(window).width() < 1066)
    {

        isMob=0;

    }
    else
    {

        isMob=1;

    }
    //chrome .hide Function Fix
    $('.menuBar').css('display', 'inline-block');
    isMob=0;

}   

alert(isMob);'
```

I thought I was declaring the variable in a proper spot. Apparently I am not. Can anyone else see the error? I surely cannot. o.O

Comment: Because you didn't actually call the function that assigns it a value.

Comment: im afraid i dont follow

Answer (score 0):

If the code posted is the entire code, then you are never calling the function that is assigning `isMob()` its value. You may try setting it to 0 while defining it in the first row or call `scaleSite()` function before `alert(isMob);`

Answer (score 0):

call `scaleSite()` in you code some where so it will call rest of your function where assignment is happening.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var isMob;
 var mobMenClicked = false;
 var scrnRefresh = false;
 scaleSite();
 $('.mobileMen').click(launchMenu);  
 
 });



function scaleSite()
{               
   // scaleVideo();
    scaleMenu();        
}   



function scaleMenu()
{
    isMob=0;
    if($(window).width() < 1066)
    {

        isMob=0;

    }
    else
    {

        isMob=1;

    }
    //chrome .hide Function Fix
    $('.menuBar').css('display', 'inline-block');
    isMob=0;

    alert(isMob);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```